# Edit a column value, with buttons, not typing manually

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a question. From image below, wow do i change the status from CREATED, to VERIFIED just by clicking on the VERIFIED BUTTON. I do not want to click on the radio button to edit this. i want to edit the value by using the Verified button. thanks. At the moment, to edit the status, i need to click on radio button and change it. I want to change it just by clicking on the Verified button.

[image]

below are my buttons

```
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verified" class="btn btn-default" />
```

and below is my controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(ListOfItems objGetListOfItems)
        {
            if (objGetListOfItems == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ListOfItems LOIEdit = ARSharedDAL.Find(objGetListOfItems);
            if (LOIEdit == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(LOIEdit);
        }
```

This is where it links to stored proc

```
    public static ListOfItems Find(ListOfItems objGetListOfItems)
    { //
        SqlDataReader rdrDataAccess = null;

        ListOfItems objListOfItems = null;

        SqlConnection database = new SqlConnection(MyCOODataConn.MyCOOConnectionString);

        database.Open();
        SqlCommand databaseCmd = new SqlCommand("SP_APP_SUI_ListOfItemsDetails", database);
        databaseCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        databaseCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idShared", objGetListOfItems.idshared));

        rdrDataAccess = databaseCmd.ExecuteReader();

        objListOfItems = new ListOfItems();

        while (rdrDataAccess.Read())
        {
            objListOfItems = new ListOfItems();

            objListOfItems.idshared = GeneralUtil.GetDBInt(rdrDataAccess, "idshared");
            objListOfItems.reftab = GeneralUtil.GetDBString(rdrDataAccess, "reftab", "");
            objListOfItems.codeShared = GeneralUtil.GetDBString(rdrDataAccess, "code", "");
            objListOfItems.abbreviation = GeneralUtil.GetDBString(rdrDataAccess, "abbreviation", "");
            objListOfItems.description = GeneralUtil.GetDBString(rdrDataAccess, "description", "");
            objListOfItems.remarks = GeneralUtil.GetDBString(rdrDataAccess, "remarks", "");
            objListOfItems.effectivedate = GeneralUtil.GetDBString(rdrDataAccess, "effectivedate", "");
            objListOfItems.Status = GeneralUtil.GetDBString(rdrDataAccess, "Status", "");


        }

        return objListOfItems;
    }
```

**EDIT** view code

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="widgetbox">
        <h4 class="widgettitle">Manage Reference Table</h4>

        <div class="widgetcontent">

            <div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Label("No :", htmlAttributes: new { style = "width: 70px; " })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.idshared, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Ref Tab :", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reftab, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reftab, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Code :", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.codeShared, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.codeShared, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Label("Abbreviation :", new { style = "padding-right: 10px; " })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.abbreviation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.abbreviation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table style="text-align:left;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Label("Description :", new { style = "padding-right: 10px; " })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.description, new { style = "width: 150px;" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table>
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Remarks :", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.remarks, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.remarks, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Effective Date:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.effectivedate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.effectivedate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Status:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Status, "CREATED", new {  }) CREATED
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Status, "VERIFIED", new { }) VERIFIED

                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />

                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verified" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the whole view code?

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig here mirza.

Comment: you will need javascript to do this. If you are using jQuery, use $.ajax and on the success callback, $('input[value="CREATED").attr('checked','checked');

also remove the Html.BeginForm()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a success handler for your post call and put this in your success handler

```
$("input[value='verified']").prop("checked", true);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shweta612/t1adhnxn/) is a simple fiddle. Unlike this fiddle you might want to put that code in success handler of verification call to ensure the data is actually verified from db.
Also if you don't want to allow users to select the radio buttons, you might want to keep them disabled.

---

Just a suggestion. From User experience point of view, It would look better if

1. You give a checkbox to show whether the data is verified (Verified : [check])
2. Show some green colored label that says verified, which appears after the data is verified.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it. thanks guys. Im so sorry if my questions were unclear.

What i required was to change the status from CREATED to VERIFIED without using the radio buttons. what i did was, i just use jquery to change the status. instead of using the radio button, i created a hidden textbox that will have value 'VERIFIED'. it will carry the value 'VERIFIED' once the button VERIFIED is clicked. below is my hidden textbox and jquery code

```
   <div class="col-md-10" hidden>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Status, new { id = "Statusd", name = "Testname1" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })




</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Verified").click(function(){
            $('#Statusd').val('ENDORSED');
        });
    });
</script>
```

thank you so much for your time guys.

Comment: If it is a Boolean field I would recommend using hidden checkbox. It could be confusing to follow your code for other team members and handling statuses in strings is always risky as small spelling mistakes can cause big problems.

Comment: @shwetaOnStack i was thinking the same. ill bring this up to the team. thanks for pointing out. =)

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult Edit(ListOfItems objGetListOfItems)
        {
            if (objGetListOfItems == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ListOfItems LOIEdit = ARSharedDAL.Find(objGetListOfItems);
            if (LOIEdit == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(LOIEdit);
        }
```

Comment: isn't this my controller?